# fatal: HTTP request failed trying to clone a GIT repo

Tags: git

I am getting a HTTP request failed when trying to clone a GIT repo

```
> git clone https://username:pwd@github.com/repo/github-codedeploy.git
```

Comment: Did you properly setup your SSL certificates?

Comment: My advice to you would be to work through a setup tutorial.  You can use SO along the way.  If you get stuck at a particular point, come back with a focused question.